# Error during Ajax Delete operation in Telerik Grid for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a simple Telerik Grid for ASP.NET MVC with Ajax delete command.  The deleting works, however, the page displays an error, and doesn't update.

I would also like to call custom JavaScript upon AJAX call return, but can't figure out where to put the code.

Here's the view:

```
Html.Telerik()
    .Grid<ScenarioVm>(Model)
    .Name("scenarioGrid")
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
        .Ajax()
        .Delete("Delete", "Scenario")
        .Select("Index", "Scenario"))
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.Id))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Template(o => o.Name)
            .Title("Scenario")
            .FooterTemplate(@<text>Total @Model.Count()</text>);
        columns.Bound(o => o.IsLocked);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ContractMonth);
        columns.Bound(o => o.CreateDate);
        columns.Command(commands => commands
                .Delete()
                .ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image))
            .Title("Delete");
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scroll => scroll.Height(200))
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDelete("onDelete")))
```

The Javascript that gets called before the AJAX call:

```
function onDelete(e) {
    var scenario = e.dataItem;
    if (scenario.CanDelete == false) {
        alert("Can not delete " +
            e.dataItem.Name +
            ": there exists a solution!");
        return false;
    } else {
        $.blockUI({
            css: {
                border: 'none',
                padding: '15px',
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                opacity: .5,
                color: '#fff'
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[GridAction]
public ActionResult Delete(Scenario scenario)
{
    Logger.Info("Delete scenario " + scenario);
    if (scenario == null)
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    try
    {
        _scenarioRepository.Delete(scenario);
        Logger.Info("Successfully deleted " + scenario);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Error(scenario + e.Message, e);
        var result = new JsonResult
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet,
            Data = new {
                ErrorCode = 1,
                ErrorMessage = e.GetType() + ": " + e.Message
            }
        };

        return result;
    }

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly you want to javascript function to be executed when operation is done. Last row in the example source code is to define callback for OnComplete event.

```
.ClientEvents(events => events
            .OnLoad("onLoad")
            .OnEdit("onEdit")
            .OnDetailViewCollapse("onDetailViewCollapse")
            .OnDetailViewExpand("onDetailViewExpand")
            .OnDelete("onDelete")
            .OnSave("onSave")
            .OnDataBinding("onDataBinding")
            .OnRowDataBound("onRowDataBound")
            .OnRowSelect("onRowSelect")
            .OnDataBound("onDataBound")
            .OnColumnResize("onColumnResize")
            .OnColumnReorder("onColumnReorder")
            .OnComplete("onComplete"))
```

[Telerik documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnComplete) has also an example how to define OnComplete event.

Comment: `.ClientEvents(events => events.OnDelete("onDelete").OnComplete("onComplete"))` causes a compile error:Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridClientEventsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'OnComplete' and no extension method 'OnComplete' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridClientEventsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things I see wrong with the code above. First, the client event [`OnDelete`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnDelete) will trigger on the client *before* the request is sent to the server. If you want the results of your Ajax call to the server you need to handle the [`OnComplete`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnComplete) event. This event fires *after* the Ajax call to the server is complete and the result is returned to the client.

Second, the GridAction action filter expects you to return a value of type [`IGridAction`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/t_telerik_web_mvc_igridmodel.html) to your view. Since you are not returning the expected value it gives you an error on the client. Here's an example of what your Controller method might look like:

```
[HttpPost]
[GridAction]
public ActionResult Delete(Scenario scenario)
{
    // Delete item and perform other operations as required
    var data = ... // Get an updated data set, with the deleted item removed
    var model = new GridModel<ScenarioVm>(data);
    return View(model);
}
```

Here's an [article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-data-binding-ajax-binding.html) discussing Ajax binding in detail on Telerik's site.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I tried returning ` return View(BuildViewModel());` from the controller Delete() method, it causes error 500 on the server.

Comment: I need both OnDelete and OnComplete events, to execute code before and after the AJAX call. How do I specify the OnComplete handler? "ClientEvents(events => events.OnDelete("onDelete").OnComplete("onComplete"))" causes a syntax error.

Comment: @jprusakova Did you define the onComplete JavaScript function?

Comment: @Tx3 I had to upgrade Telerik library, in order to get this to work.  Thanks!